# Drawable. Draw doesn't draw image to the screen

Tags: android

```
public class BackgammonBoardView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    /***
     * @author
     * The threads class definition
     */
    class BBVThread extends Thread 
    {

        //mSurfaceHolder and mHandler are part of the thread.
        //mContext is part of the container SurfaceView
        private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
        private Handler mHandler;

        //The threads constructor
        public BBVThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context,
                Handler handler) {

            Log.d(TAG,"BBVThread. Constructor.");

            mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            mHandler = handler;
            mContext = context;

            mDiceCup = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.dicecup);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.d(TAG,"BBVThread. run.");

            Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {

                    Log.d(TAG,"Draw the dice cup...");

                    mDiceCup.setBounds(0, 0, 120,120);
                    mDiceCup.draw(canvas);

                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (canvas != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }//end run    
    }
    /****
     * end of the BBVThread class
     */

    /* ########################################
     * # BackgammonBoardView Member Variables #
     * ######################################## */
    private Drawable mDiceCup;
    /*
     * End BackGammonBoardView Member Variables
     */

    public BackgammonBoardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        Log.d(TAG,"SurfaceView Constructor.");

        //register out interest in hearing about changes to our surface
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

        thread = new BBVThread(holder, context, new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message m) {

            }
        });


        setFocusable(true); // make sure we get key events
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) 
    {

            //Start the thread. This will initiate run which will do the first draw
            thread.start();

            //Norify that the surface has been created
            Log.d(TAG,"SurfaceView. surfaceCreated.");
    }
}
```

I'm following the kind of code that I'm seeing in the LunarLander example. I created a res/drawable folder. Previously the images I had in res/drawable-hdpi however when I didn't see an image drawn to the canvas I created res/drawable and copied the .png's into that folder. My call to R.drawable.dicecup is resolved without any syntax errors. The image is 120 x 120 pixels as I sized it in my image editor. I was surprised when I opened the application and there is no dice cup image drawn anywhere. What could be wrong?

The thread is actually started in the surfaceCreated method. I'm getting Log.d's from run so I know run is executing. Theres no errors as far as I can tell and the program doesn't crash or anything just nothing is drawn.

I've tried moving the draw back into the UI thread but I still see nothing.

P.S. This turned out to be very much my fault. The Bitmap draws fine from the thread it was just being obliterated by the rectangle I am using for my background image and I had not discovered that yet. It should help now that I understand how to draw a bitmap to spot these types of problems. To make things as easy right now I created res/drawables and am loading the images from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to call draw on a thread other than the UI thread. If that's what you're doing, then that's why its not working. According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads), you cant do any UI work on non-UI threads.

Comment: OK. That you so much for pointing this out to me. Is there a work around? As well the LunarLander example seeems to not care that bitmaps are being drawn from a thread. Why this discrepancy?

Comment: replace mDiceCup.draw() with post(new Runnable() {mDiceCup.draw()});

Comment: I'm trying to replace the syntax but there are some errors.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "draw", Identifier expected after this token
 - The type new Runnable(){} must implement the inherited abstract method 
  Runnable.run()

Comment: oh, right. sorry, the code should read post(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {mDiceCup.draw()}}); just type "post(new Runnable()" and eclipse should do the rest for you if you autocomplete

Comment: OK but the draw method takes a parameter canvas like mDiceCup.draw(canvas). How am I supposed to get canvas into the post?

Comment: you already have a reference to canvas. just use that one, and make sure to add a final modifier to the Canvas variable declaration

Comment: Still no image is drawn.

Comment: Since I moved the Drawable draw outside the thread and into the UI thread. Still I see no image

Comment: It draws fine from thread. My problem was that it was that the image was being obliterated by the rectangle I'm using for my background color.

Comment: Thank you kmdupr33 for helping. I have to use all this as a learning experience.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt more helpful. I'm not super familiar with SurfaceView

Comment: You did very well. What you told me was enough to get me to see what was wrong. I appreciate what you told me.